# Opening a File from assets folder in android

Tags: android, android-assets

I have a .gif file inside the assets folder like this assets/Files/android.gif. when I try to open the file it throws an exception at the second line

```
AssetManager mngr=getAssets();
InputStream is2=mngr.open("Files/android.gif");
```

so Is it that I'm trying to open an image file despite that the same code works if I try to open a text file ?
what can be the problem here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These Lines are working perfectly--

```
InputStream assetInStream=null;

try {
    assetInStream=getAssets().open("icon.png");
    Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetInStream);
    img.setImageBitmap(bit);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(assetInStream!=null)
    assetInStream.close();
}
```

If your image is very big then you should scale your image before decoding it into Bitmap. [See How to display large image efficiently](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/displaying-bitmaps-efficiently-and.html)

Comment: AFIK stream should be closed after use

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you are getting complaints about unhandled exception type IOException. If that's the case, you need to put the call to mgr.open in a try-catch block to handle the exception that may occur when retrieving the InputStream object.

```
AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
try {
    InputStream is2 = mngr.open("Files/android.gif");
} catch (final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if things have changed or not but I had an app in Android 1.1 that opened icons to then display them in a view and I did it like so:

```
BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(mContext.openFileInput(value));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the preferred way to do this is to put your image in the res/drawable directory.  Then you can get a Drawable like this:

```
Drawable d = Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(R.drawable.android);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mina, I had the same problem... I had images and an XML file within "assets" and I could read the XML file but not the images. After a couple of hours of frustration I finally found the solution !

I have posted the solution here:
[Null-pointer issue displaying an image from assets folder Android 2.2 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038597/null-pointer-issue-displaying-an-image-from-assets-folder-android-2-2-sdk/5902816#5902816)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe gif is supported automatically on Android.  Try a png or jpg with the same code.