# IOException when reading AssetFileDescriptor

Tags: android, android-resources, android-assets

I'm trying to read a bitmap from the Android `/assets` folder using the following code:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = getAssets().openFd("pic1.jpg")
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFileDescriptor());
```

The exception I'm getting suggests that the file permissions are wrong:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:432)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:309)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:670)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:688)
```

Attempting to read it from the input stream yields a similar exception:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = getAssets().openFd("pic1.jpg");
FileInputStream is = fd.createInputStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

The exception:

```
java.io.IOException: lseek failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
Stack trace:
  at java.io.FileInputStream.skip(FileInputStream.java:197)
  at android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream.<init>(AssetFileDescriptor.java:173)
  at android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor.createInputStream(AssetFileDescriptor.java:138)
```

Reading directly from the input stream gives yet another exception:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("pic1.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: asset
  at android.content.res.AssetManager.seekAsset(Native Method)
  at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$600(AssetManager.java:35)
  at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.mark(AssetManager.java:567)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:572)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:643)
```

What's the correct way to read assets?

Comment: try `AssetFileDescriptor fd = getAssets().openFd("/pics/" + assets[i])`

Comment: That throws a `FileNotFoundException`, which is also what I receive when I provide a file name that doesn't exist.

Comment: try in this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/5903226/1436931

Comment: Took a little debugging, but eventually determined that that results in the same exception; I'll update the question with the stack trace.

Comment: Oddly, the resource *does* appear for a moment before the application crashes. I hypothesize that the asset is trying to be read twice due to a bug elsewhere in my code. I'll simplify matters and get back here in a moment.

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("pic1.jpg"))` does appear to work, but crashes with the trace above when I attempt to load multiple assets in parallel from a background thread. Perhaps the method is not thread-safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't reading the asset from the main thread. In the application I was developing, two list items could concurrently loading the same, rather large, asset.

In short, if that file was still being read while another thread attempted to access it, an `IOException` would be thrown with "lseek failed: EBADF (Bad file number)".

Comment: @amal It was quite a headache to debug this, so I feel your pain.