# Loading images from assets

Tags: android, assets, baseadapter

i have been working on wallpaper app for a while and it's almost done but the size of app is pretty big cause i use .png extension so currently i'm trying to load jpg via assets instead of png in res

i tried to implement this answer 
[Images from Assets folder in a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752924/android-images-from-assets-folder-in-a-gridview)
i get an error while loading the imageadapter

- 02-21 23:13:05.883: E/AndroidRuntime(17634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
- 02-21 23:13:05.883: E/AndroidRuntime(17634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagieview05/com.example.imagieview05.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private GridView mGridView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView1);

    Bitmap[] mBitArray  = new Bitmap[4];
    try {
    mBitArray[0] = getBitmapFromAssets("g1p2.jpg");
    mBitArray[1] = getBitmapFromAssets("g1p1.jpg");
    mBitArray[2] = getBitmapFromAssets("g1p3.jpg");
    mBitArray[3] = getBitmapFromAssets("g1p4.jpg");

    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }


  mGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this ,mBitArray));

}
public Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets (String filename) throws IOException{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = assetManager.open(filename);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;  
}




  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


private Context mContext;
private Bitmap[] mImageArray;


public GallaryAdapter(Context c, Bitmap[] mBitArray) {
    c = mContext;
    mBitArray = mImageArray;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImageArray.length;
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mImageArray[position];
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView imgView = new ImageView(mContext);
     imgView.setImageBitmap(mImageArray[position]);
     //put black borders around the image
     imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
     imgView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120, 120));
     return imgView;

}
```

here is the  original  working code without Assets reference

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridView =  (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView1);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Context mContext;


    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.g1p1, R.drawable.g1p2,
            R.drawable.g1p3, R.drawable.g1p4,
            R.drawable.g1p5, R.drawable.g1p6,
            R.drawable.g1p22, R.drawable.g1p33,
            R.drawable.g1p44, R.drawable.g1p55,
            R.drawable.g1p5, R.drawable.g1p6,
            R.drawable.g1p22, R.drawable.g1p33,
            R.drawable.g1p44, R.drawable.g1p55



    };
};
```

thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mBitArray = mImageArray; its pointing mBitArray toward mImageArray witch is nothing, maybe?

i dont think it really matters if you use jpeg or png memory wise anyway, in the program its going to completely uncompress the jpeg anyway

Comment: well i use about 13 pics the total size of apk is 8.5 mb in case of png and 2.5 mb in case of Jpg

Comment: when i tried to debug mbitarray returns [null, null, null, null]

Comment: before or after you put it in the new ImageAdapter because your method to load the images is right, i still think its mBitArray = mImageArray that should be mImageArray = mBitArray

Comment: before i pass it to adapter i think thats the reason the app crash

Comment: well im still a beginner, i never used gridview or baseadapter, sorry if i couldnt help

Comment: thanks anyway :D i think i might just use ordinary png source maybe this code is too complex for me

Comment: i was able to load the pictures from assets to my GRidview but i don't know how to get certain pic from my Bitmap array via position

Comment: what about all the methods in your imageadapter

Comment: i tried to return Bitmap from imageadapter via                       `codepublic Bitmap getBitMap(int position) throws IOException { 
  
  AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
  String[] list = am.list("Gallary");
   BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(am.open(list[position]));
   
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
   
  buf.close();
        return bitmap;
 } `

Comment: as you can see i created Bitmap via assetmanager and Selected certain Position my AssetManager opens "Gallary" to list the images but it doesn't work unless i put them in The Root of Assets folder   i don't know why it should loads from Gallary folder not the Root btw if i let the MBitarray load from The Root my Assetmanager works if i change my Mbitarray to load from Gallary folder my Asssetmanger won't woork any idea?

Comment: btw thanks for ur support as my first app it means a lot for me

Comment: put in the root/gallary, im guessing

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code loader images from assets folder following the example [code](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

```
private Bitmap decodeStreamFromAssets(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    InputStream ims = null;

    try {

        ims = getAssets().open(path);
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims, null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims, null, options);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

        if (ims != null) {
            try {

                ims.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Load *.jpg work, but *.png not work for ex.

IMG // work

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeStreamFromAssets("test.jpg", 64, 64);
    if(bitmap1 != null){

        imageViewTest.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else {

        Log.e("ERROR", "error");
    }
```

PNG // not work ( is error )

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeStreamFromAssets("test.png", 64, 64);
    if(bitmap1 != null){

        imageViewTest.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else {

        Log.e("ERROR", "error");
    }
```