# Display images in spinner placed in res folder

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have images placed in following path

res>drawable>Images>Currencies>[All images]

I have made a custom spinner Adapter.

```
viewHolder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.UICurrencyCurrencyFlag);
            viewHolder.flag.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

How can i set these images in my ImageView. Images format is `png`

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1. Put all images in drawable folders without subfolders.
2. Put all images in asset with your folder structures.

The differences are:

1. If you go for approach 1, you can retrieve the resource by id. (R.drawable.*)
2. If you go for approach 2, you get to maintain your folders, but you need to read the resource as raw.

To open file in asset folder, you can refer to a previous post:
[Opening a File from assets folder in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933015/opening-an-image-file-inside-the-assets-folder)

Suggestion:

Rename your file as images_currency_image1.jpg to avoid subfolders but keep unique-ness.
I am not sure if this help in your situation.

Comment: okay they are currency flags like PKR.PNG USD.PNG Etc. i have USD saved in a string. so i can just add .png to create filename. Now R.drawable.* seems useless because i can't append filename i think. If i use asset folder then what should i do?

Comment: I added a reference link for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to make subfolders inside `drawable` folder. And even if you do, you can't access the contents inside it. And it doesn't even make sense. Why you need subfolders when android is taking care of giving you the drawables by their id. You place your images directly into `res/drawable` folder like `res/drawable/[All images]`. And then try to access by `R.drawable.UICurrencyCurrencyFlag` and not `R.id.UICurrencyCurrencyFlag`. All the best.

Comment: i need to place them in another folder, i can put them in asset folder too if that is easy?

Comment: No. You can't make any subfolder inside drawable. Or even if you do, you can't access the files inside it. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

if u place in assets folder u can access in following manner
              InputStream bitmap;
          try {
        bitmap = getAssets().open("icon.png");
         Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
           ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myId);
           img.setImageBitmap(bit);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }