# Where do I put the image resource file? BitmapFactory.decodeFile()

Tags: android, bitmap, resources, directory, bitmapfactory

I am trying to use this:

> BitmapFactory.decodeFile("logo.jpg")

and I don't seem to have the file: logo.jpg in the right place in comparison to my apk. where should it go?

P.S. the error I get is:[image]

**Edit**

I now am using this: >BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),"logo.jpg")

and am now getting a compiler error that says:

> The method getActivity() is undefined for the type Brick
>   (Brick is the name of the class)

I don't care which solution works as long as one of them does

Comment: Currently where is your logo file?

Comment: well in an attempt to get lucky Ive put a copy several places ;). In bin and bin\res and bin\res\drawable-hdpi and bin\res\drawable-mdpi and and bin\res\drawable-xhdpi and and bin\res\drawable-xxhdpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to put an JPG file into your project and load via Java code, is that correct.

If so, you'll need to put your `logo.jpg` into your `assets` folder,

and load it using the similar method as this SO answer stated:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502231/763459

---

For your convenience I pasted the code as below:

```
InputStream bitmap=null;

try {
    bitmap=getAssets().open("logo.png");
    Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
    img.setImageBitmap(bit);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(bitmap!=null)
    bitmap.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where would you like to put your "logo.jpg" file?

1. If you would like to put it in the drawable folder, then use:

   ```
   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
   ```
2. If you would like to put it somewhere on your device's memory, then use:

   ```
   BitmapFactory.decodeResource("/sdcard/logo.jpg");
   ```

And here's some guide to help you start: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Comment: when I try the getResources() I get an error saying: getResources() is undefined. is there a specific using I need?

Comment: Try `getActivity().getResources()`

Comment: same thing except getActivity is undefined now

Comment: Well, it may bother you for a minute, but can you post your code? It might be helpful.