# NullPointerException in android

Tags: java, android

Here i am try to open photo from folder which i saved in before activity of this program's but here i still face the Exception.

```
ImageView img = null;
Bitmap bmp = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photoeffect_1);
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    String s = i.getStringExtra("second");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/GWonderPhoto/"+s+".jpg");
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Exception :

> '02-25 17:07:07.543: E/BitmapFactory(24805): Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/GWonderPhoto/1424905623242.jpg:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)'

Comment: Check the image path !

Comment: Log says '(No such file or directory)'. @Rami is right! Check the path

Comment: Try changing `decodeFile("/sdcard/GWonderPhoto/"+s+".jpg");` to : `decodeFile("file://" +"/sdcard/GWonderPhoto/"+s+".jpg");` or to : `decodeFile("content://sdcard/GWonderPhoto/"+s+".jpg");`

Comment: @Josef Still not Working

Comment: Here is solution for you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939733/where-do-i-put-the-image-resource-file-bitmapfactory-decodefile

Answer (score 3):

use

```
setContentView(R.layout.photoeffect_1);
```

just after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

i.e. rewrite `onCreate` method as

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.photoeffect_1);
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    String s = i.getStringExtra("second");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/GWonderPhoto/"+s+".jpg");
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: @GautamPatadiya because your image path is wrong as it says `ENOENT (No such file or directory)'`

Comment: still face problem here

Comment: @GautamPatadiya which problem,please be more clear,Did you clear your project?

Comment: sir first as your suggestion i edit my code but then after image doesn't load in imageVIew

Comment: @GautamPatadiya did you get any exception,please check image path

Comment: 02-25 17:18:53.343: E/BitmapFactory(25994): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/GWonderPhoto/1424906328300 .jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: sir but if i try to access a particular image for example '12121.jpg' then it will show me but dynamically that doesn't show

Comment: @GautamPatadiya replace `bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/GWonderPhoto/"+s+".jpg");` with    `bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/GWonderPhoto/12121.jpg");` and check if it working or not?

Comment: @GautamPatadiya then debug and check the value of `s`(it may be empty.).

Comment: Excetly you right but i show Toast ,That show me the image name

Comment: @GautamPatadiya thwn what is the value of `s`?

Comment: from before activity i pass the timestamp which is catch by 's' variable then after i append the '.jpg' extension but the name i can see in Toast but image still doesn't

Answer (score 0):

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/GWonderPhoto/"+s+".jpg");
```

change this line to:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GWonderPhoto/"+s+".jpg");
```

**EDIT**

also see if following permissions are added in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you but that still throws Exception