# How to set ImageView using the name String of the local resource avoiding conditional mapping of resources

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-resources

I want to set an ImageView programatically, passing the name of the local resource drawable as String.

The drawable clearly are int identified in this way

```
 R.drawable.mydrawable_name
```

How could I do to solve this problem without map everything in a conditional switch?

I want to avoid something in this form

```
if(myString.equal"stringname_1"){
   myImageview.setImageResource( R.drawable.stringname_1);
}
else if(myString.equal"stringname_1")....
etc
```

Comment: so what will be your input for the drawable you written

Comment: I think this might help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328376/what-path-format-should-i-use-with-bitmapfactory-decodefilestring-pathname/17349998#17349998

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use getResources().getIdentifier() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) for this purpose. For your code it would look something like this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(myString, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
myImageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

The code above assumes you're in an Activity.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately I'm not in an activity and cannot compile due to getResources() results not defined

Comment: From where are you calling this code then. Passing through a reference to a context or activity should be fairly straight forward. Post more of your code in case you need help with it.

Comment: this code is used in a loader for a custom list view, so if I have understood should I pass the context from the activity that shows the list view to the listview manager and from the listview manager to loader?

Comment: Yes. Passing through the activity through the chain works. You might also want to expose a getActivity() method in your listview manager and hold on to it there instead of passing it through all the way. depends on your preference

Comment: just want to mention here, that `mystring` will only contains the filename/imagename and NOT `R.drawable.filename`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using java reflection

```
        Field field = R.drawable.class.getDeclaredField("mydrawable_name");

        int a = field.getInt(this);
```

a will have the id value of `R.drawable.mydrawable_name` . Now you can use this id to set image

Comment: hmmm the first line is slow

Answer (score 0):

Pl Note: Below one is need to be comment for the accepted answer but I dont have previlage to add comment.

`getDrawable(id)` is deprecated now instead we can use

```
getDrawable(int id, Resources.Theme theme)
```

Return a drawable object associated with a particular resource ID and styled for the specified theme.

`getTheme` return the current theme.

Sample is given below:

```
Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(id, context.getTheme());
```