# Androidstudio Paths.get not found

Tags: java, android, file, path

How can I specify the path to the desired file? I Have a .txt file in the assets directory (below main directory).

```
try {
    readDataFromFile = new String(Files.readAllBytes((Paths.get("secondlevel.txt"))));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I get the correct path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening a File from assets folder in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933015/opening-a-file-from-assets-folder-in-android)

Comment: Somewhat, thanks. I also just realized that, for some reason, Arrays.toString does not print out the entire string but just the first entries. The only thing that works is a long for loop that prints everything individually. I spent the last hour trying to understand why not the entire string was taken from file. Ah the wonders of programming. Thanks for taking the time to answer me